# How can an iOS App not charge for bandwidth?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iPhone 4s with Telus in Canada. Telus has a dedicated app for checking account details, etc. In this app, it states that "No data charges will be incurred when using the app, even while outside Canada". How does this work?

Does Telus monitor your traffic to `*.telus.com` and not count it on your bill?

Or does the app make special web requests that Telus recognizes as someone using their app? And then they can credit this on someone's account.

I ask this because the app, for the most part, is a shell to various web pages. So if you could figure out how to get the app to go to a site like `google.com` then you could theoretically browse any site for free on their network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All telecoms record traffic to and from your phone and the IP. Since the telecom is the company that gives the IP out, they can record the inbound and outbound traffic and take it off your bill. If outside of the region, you access the site, they will get a billing from the roaming partner you are on with the IP, IMEI, and sites you went to.

So, to answer your question: No, you can't make special web requests with an app to circumvent those controls since your phone, in a sense, would be hitting a website not registered at telus as their corporate site